# PHP - Using sessions to update login information

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login page that is directed towards another php page. This php page takes the username the user entered, stores it as a session variable, then redirects to home.php (this code is run after the information is validated).

```
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE usertable SET loginStatus='Logged in' WHERE userName = '$username'");
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    header("Location: home.php");
```

This will update the appropriate column without an issue. I put the following code in the home.php page to display each users login status

```
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    if(empty($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("Location: login.php");
    }

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM usertable");
    echo "Logged in as ". $_SESSION['username'];
    echo "<br />";
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo $row['userName'] . " " . $row['emailAddress'] . " " .$row['loginStatus'];
    echo "<br />";
    }

    ?>

    <p><a href=logout.php>Click here to logout</a></p>
```

When the user clicks the logout link, it directs them to the following php page:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $update1 = mysql_query("UPDATE usertable SET loginStatus='' WHERE userName = '$username'");
    echo $username;
    ?>
    <?php
    session_destroy();
    ?>
    <h1>You are now logged out</h1>
    <p><a href=login.php>login</a></p>
```

This is where I have my issue. MySQL is not updating the loginStatus of the corresponding username. All the variables I have ($username, $username1) print out the correct information when I test them. In the case of the logout page I know that $_SESSION['username'] is storing the correct user name, but I can not figure out why it will not update the value in the database.

Comment: I see you're not checking the result of your update query; is it `false` perhaps? You could `echo` the query, does it look strange?

Comment: Where is the database conexion in the logout page?

Comment: echoing $update1 from the logout page doesn't return anything, if that is what you meant?

Comment: Oh embarrassing, you were right EmCo i needed to start the connection on the page. This fixes my issue.

Comment: This is toy for hackers. Plz know about mysql injections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is all to your page, you might have no database connection. Check the return value of your query with at least

```
$update1 = mysql_query("UPDATE usertable SET loginStatus='' WHERE userName = '$username'") or die(mysql_error());
```

and you should see the real cause.

Besides, you should consider switching to either `mysqli` or `PDO`, because `mysql_*` functions are deprecated by now.

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly is your problem??...database updating on login or database fetching on home.php page or database updating on logout page...also how many times do you start your sessions all three pages have session start functions on them.

Comment: updating on logout page is the issue, I had the impression that starting a session was necessary to retrieve the variables.